# Symfony on Godaddy windows hosting

Tags: windows, godaddy, shared-hosting

I uploaded all symfony framework files to my godaddy windows shared hosting that supports php5 but I cannot access when I try to type the folder path? It shows a 401 authentication error but when I uploaded a normal php file it was working perfectly. Could it be an issue with .htaccess file as I found that there is not htaccess in windows hosting. Someone please help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use Symfony (v2 or v1, BTW?) without modification VirtHost settings **for development**.
Htaccess is useful, but nor virthost spec nor htaccess contain nothing for basic http-auth.

I have a working (WAMP) Symfony 1.x host and can show (and understand) it's config.

In common, on-site instruction for starting Symfony is rather full and detailed, without `Alias /sf  ...` it will not work (based on own experience).